# How to concat two values in one column using import.io

Tags: import.io

I am writing extractor for newegg.com using import.io. I am facing one difficulty while grabbing price values from listing page.

```
  <div class="item-price-now">
    <span>from</span>
     $
    <strong>108</strong>
    <sup>.00</sup>
    </div>
```

Price enclosed in two nodes, **strong** and **sup**. I want to get 108.00 as one node. When i tried following Xpath, i get values in two nodes.

```
//div[@class="item-price-now"]//strong/text() | //div[@class="item-price-now"]//sup/text()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an xpath to just grab all the text within the div, then use a regular expression to filter it just to the text after the dollar.

xpath: `//div[@class='item-price-now']` -> `from $108.00`

regex: `\$d+\.\d+` -> `$108.00`